# videopress videos are not displayed when loading the content with ajax in a lightbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, videos

I'm using videopress and I'm adding the videos into posts with the videopress shortcode, and when I visit the post I can see the videos and play them, but the problem is when loading the post with ajax and place just part of the content that contains the video in  a lightbox, the videos are not displayed, someone can help me with this?, is it a problem with ajax when loading just part of the content?, thanks.

Comment: A link to such an URL would help.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you find a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem and in my case it is because when I load the page, the videopress scripts are loaded if the content of that page has a videopress. As there are no videos at first these plugins are not loaded. So when I open the video with Ajax it crashes.